# Why am I getting "sd" as my text? using Jquery and Post to pass variable to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, web

I have a button of type button within a form with method post and submit button. I want to upon clicking the button (not submit) to pass value of username input to php but it does not work
what is the issue  please help

Note :
input username gets a value
button retrieveQ is clicked and invokes the post method written in head
then at the end of it getQuestion in php is called and value of user through a database is echo into innerhtml of another textbox

DATABASE and everything works fine I just want the $_POST['uname'] to get me the input of username box

```html
<?php
    include ('comp424.php');

    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['users'])!="")
    {
        header("Location: home.php");
    }
    include_once 'comp424.php';

    if(isset($_POST['btn-retrieveP']))
    {
        //SQL INJECTION
        $uname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,strip_tags($_POST['username']));
        $upass = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,strip_tags($_POST['pass']));
       
        $salt = '';
        $key="ab01$%";

        $res= mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$uname'");

        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
        $salt = $row['salt'];
        $hashPass = hash ('sha512', $salt . $key . $upass);

        $count = mysqli_num_rows($res); 

        // if uname/pass correct it returns must be 1 row
        if($count == 1 && $hashPass == $row['password'] )
        {
            if(isset($_POST["captcha"])&&$_POST["captcha"]!=""&&$_SESSION["code"]==$_POST["captcha"])
            {
                //Captcha code entered correctly 
                $_SESSION['user'] = $row['userid'];
                header("Location: home.php");
            }
            else
            {
               ?>
                    <script>alert('You have entered wrong captcha');</script>

               <?php
            }


        }
        else
        {
            ?>
            <script>alert('You have entered wrong username or password!');</script>

            <?php
        }

    }


    //php function to retrieve Question for the username
    function getQuestion()
                    {   
                        
                        include ('comp424.php');
                        
                                $unamePR = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,strip_tags($_POST['username'])); 
                            
                        

                        global $question;
                        $question='sss';
                        $unamePR = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,strip_tags($user));
                        $resPR= mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$unamePR'");

                        $rowPR=mysqli_fetch_array($resPR);
                        $countPR = mysqli_num_rows($resPR); 
                        if ($countPR ==1){
                            $question = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT securityQuestion FROM users WHERE username='$unamePR'"));
                            $question = $question['securityQuestion'];
                        }else{
                            $question='No question is associated with the given Username!';
                        }
                        echo $_POST['uname'];
                    }
?>




<!DOCTYPE html >
<html >
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Comp424 Password Retrieval</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
         <script>
            
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#btn-retrieveQ").click(function () {
                        alert("ssss");
                    var username = $('#uname').val();    
                    $.post("passwordRetrieval.php", {uname: username}, function(data){
                        alert("data sent and received: "+data);
                    });



                   

                        document.getElementById("question").innerHTML= "<?php getQuestion(); ?> ";
                    });
                            });
            

                
        </script>
   
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <div id="login-form">
                <form  method="post">
                    <table align="center" width="50%" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" id="uname" name="uname" placeholder="Your Username" required />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                    <button id="btn-retrieveQ" type="button">Retrieve Question</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <p id="question">Type Your Username to Retrive Your Question</p> 
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="answer" placeholder="Your Answer"  />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="password" name="pass" id="password" placeholder="Your New Password" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input name="captcha" type="text" placeholder="Enter Captcha Below">    
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <img src="captcha.php" />  
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <button type="submit" name="btn-retrieveP">Retrieve Password</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
            </div>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can improve your question. Please read [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When your code shows your precise problem with nothing extra, you are showing respect to those who volunteer to help you.
If you format your code to eliminate scrolling, you make it easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to echo the variable in a function which you never call.  And in the main PHP code you're using `$_POST['username']` but you're posting `uname`.

Change the object of the POST variable to use what you're actually sending.

PS: You're code is very hard to read.

Comment: I do call the getQuestion function  through innerhtml at the end of my Jquery script

Comment: You can't do that.  If you want to use that function in JS you'll need to use AJAX.  You can't call PHP functions (server-side) from a client side language m.